# Search for a pattern, replace only the first 2 lines and delete the rest

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file containing an unknown number of lines that start with "class". I want to replace the content of the first 2 lines starting with "class" with some different content, and only keep these 2 lines and delete the rest.

Example:

```
school 
class A
class B
class C
class D
classroom
```

Desired output:

```
school
class X
class Y
classroom
```

I'm looking at sed but can't find a good solution for this. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Look at awk instead. With awk, it's trivial to count the number of replacements done so far and make decisions based on that count.

Comment: @berndbausch thank you for the suggestion, I will go ahead with the answer below, but will take time learning more sed and awk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **GNU sed** with extended regex mode `-E` we can use the hold space as a counter.

```
sed -Ee '
  /^class(\s|$)/!b
  G
  /\n{3}/d
  /\n{2}/s/.*/class Y/
  /\n{1}/s/.*/class X/
  p;z;H;d
' file
```

Brief explanation:

- compilation of the `sed` commands used: `b G z h H d s/// p`
- Refer to GNU sed manual about them
- Idea is to keep printing all those lines thhat do not begin with the word class
- Now, for a class line three things have to be disambiguated-is it being seen once, twice, or more than two times.
- We strap the contents of hold space on the pattern space and keep a close watch on the newlines.
- if 3 newlines found => seen more than 2 times. Promptly delete this line. No further processing takes place on it.
- if 2 newlines found => seeing for the second time so change it.
- seeing first time also make another change.
- for either of the last two cases increment hold space.

---

With  the **awk** utility it
is straightforward.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    a[1]="class X"
    a[2]="class Y"
  }
  $1 == "class" {
    if ( k++ < 2 ) {
      $0 = a[k]
    } else { next }
  }1
' file
```

**Output:**

```
school 
class X
class Y
classroom
```

Comment: I haven't tried the sed one but the awk worked like a charm, thank you very much. I chose to go with the awk since it's pretty straightforward. It would be very useful if you could give some explanation on the sed solution (sorry if it was too much to ask for, I'm not familiar with the syntax so it's not as clear to me)

Comment: @Kim made a brief explanatory section you may check.